# read alphanumeric field of json file without quote

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read alphanumeric field of json file without quote:

I tried to cast this field to String at the time of reading json But didn't work.

json file (abc.json):

```
{"col1": 1a2bc}

struct1 = StructType([StructField("col1", StringType(), True)])
df = spark.read.json(abc.json, schema=struct1)

o/p : 

>>> df.show()
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

But if i change my json file to `{"col1": '1a2bc'}` then this works file.
Could you please suggest a method to read alnum filed without quote.

Comment: JSON strings must be quoted. It is not valid JSON otherwise. What exactly are you trying to do that you need such a broken data format?

Comment: I wasn't aware that JSON string must be quoted.But I was thinking there should be a way to tell that this field is string at the runtime while reading json.

Comment: The types in a JSON are well-defined by the syntax. Are you perhaps looking for a way to specify a schema to validate your JSON?

Comment: I was looking for a way to read broken JSON data format file if I know schema.